# AWS SAM cloudformation: API Gateway can't invoke lambda (AWS::Serverless::Function )

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I created a template.yaml file to declare a simple lambda function that is invoked by api gateway. When I try to invoke the function from the api gateway url the request fails with `{"message": "Internal server error"}` and in cloudwatch api gateway logs I see the error message **Invalid permissions on Lambda function**.

This is my template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
    AliasName:
        Type: String
        Default: dev

Resources:
    DynamoDBTenantTable:
        Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
        Properties:
            AttributeDefinitions:
                - AttributeName: clientApiKey
                  AttributeType: S
            KeySchema:
                - AttributeName: clientApiKey
                  KeyType: HASH
            ProvisionedThroughput:
                ReadCapacityUnits: 5
                WriteCapacityUnits: 5
            TableName: !Sub "authtable-${AliasName}"


    AmeAuthenticatorLambda:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            Handler: authenticator.handler
            Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
            Runtime: nodejs8.10
            CodeUri: src/
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    TABLE_NAME: !Sub "authtable-${AliasName}"
            Events:
                AuthenticatorEvent:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /authentication/
                        Method: POST
```

The SAM Documentation says that the syntax above is able to [create the necessary permissions and API declaration implicitly](https://awslabs.github.io/serverless-application-model/internals/generated_resources.html#api).

I also followed an example from [AWS website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html).

If I add to the template.yaml file a *lambda:InvokeFunction* permission then the invocation works, but by reading the documentation doing that should not be necessary.

What can be going wrong?

Comment: Are you invoking the lambda from the AWS ApiGateway Console? Or from a server or your local machine?

Comment: I am invoking from my local machine using curl, I send a POST request to the api gateway URL for the stage environment, like: https://nr393i9di3e9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/LATEST/authentication/. 
Api gateway receives the request but fails to invoke the lambda